# How to make text selection increment on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to finish a program on visual studio with forms, I have a textbox(txtUser), another textbox(txtKerko) and a button(btnKerko). So the program goes like this, the user write some text on txtUser and write any word or text on txtKerko and when btnKerko is clicked that word written on txtKerko should be selected on txtUser, if there are more than one of that word all the words should be selected on every btnKerko click. It's almost ready but I couldn't do the part when there are more than one word to increment one by one. This is the event code for btnKerko :

```
private void BtnKerko_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUser.Text.Contains(txtKerko.Text) == true)
            {
                txtUser.Focus();
                string teksti = txtUser.Text;
                txtUser.SelectionStart = teksti.IndexOf(txtKerko.Text);
                txtUser.SelectionLength = txtKerko.TextLength;                              
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nuk u gjet");
            }
        }
```

Comment: is this winforms?

Comment: Yes,it's winforms

Comment: A pic of program: https://ibb.co/ZXtqLvt

Comment: Do you want every instance of `teksti` to be selected in the TextBox or do you want each instance of `teksti` to be selected one-by-one as you click `BtnKerko`? If it's the former, I'm afraid you can't make multiple selections with the TextBox control, not that I recall.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this using textbox. You can use RichTextBox for this purpose.

Comment: I want each instance of teksti to be selected one-by-one as I click btnKerko,can I make it with simple textbox?

Comment: @G3n1t0 Yes it is possible, look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it if you want to select the word one by one. You can use this code :

```
int lastIndex = 0;
private void BtnKerko_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtUser.Focus();
    int index = txtUser.Text.IndexOf(txtKerko.Text, lastIndex);

    if (index != -1)
    {
        lastIndex = index + 1;
        txtUser.SelectionStart = index;
        txtUser.SelectionLength = txtKerko.TextLength;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the variable `lastIndex` is holding the last selection in each click of the button. I guess you know that the second parameter of `IndexOf` method tells to start finding the index from that second parameter value.

Comment: Couple of things I noticed - First, this won't find the requested string if the requested string starts at index 0.  Second, if the result of your first conditional is true, you can just display the message box and return from the function; there is no need to set lastIndex at all.  You could then also get rid of the second conditional since you would have already exited if the string isn't found and just run the three lines of code.  Last, it will also find the requested string as a substring of other strings:  example would be finding "the" in "other".

Comment: @Brad Good findings. I corrected the code for your first finding. For the second finding, i don't think the first condition is necessary, so i removed that. And about the last one, you are correct, but i think what i provided here will solve the OP's problem. I know this idea can me made more perfect and you are welcome to make another answer with this. I just made a quick solution for him.

Comment: I don't think there's need for a separate answer.  I was going to make an answer, saw yours, liked yours more than what I had, tested yours, found a few things, and that's that.  It would be up to the OP on what specific behavior is desired and what is not.

Comment: @G3n1t0 It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Don't thank us, rather follow [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: `.Text.ToString()`? Twice.

Comment: @Jimi Where is it twice?

Comment: `txtUser.Text.ToString()` + `txtKerko.Text.ToString()`. `Text` is already `string`. It's like writing: `if (Convert.ToBoolean(txtKerko.Enabled) == true) ...`. It doesn't look very good, right?

Comment: Even most of the time i write `if (Convert.ToBoolean(txtKerko.Enabled) == true)` to make it more readable, but yes your are right, this is redundant and we can easily avoid this, though it's not an issue.